# How to convert a list into a list of lists in python

Tags: python

Here is an example of a list that I would like to convert into a list of lists in python:

p=[1,2,3,4]

I wrote the following code to address the problem:

```
u=[]
v=[x for x in p]
u.append(v)
```

my result: `[[1,2,3,4]]`

```
Result I would like to have: **[[1],[2],[3],[4]]**
```

Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make a small tweak to your list comprehension, and wrap the `x` in brackets to put each element in a list.

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> v = [[x] for x in p]
>>> v
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: Many thanks Nitzle, I have solved  similar problem in the past, but just couldn't think straight today.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
u = [[x] for x in p]
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answer have depicted, List Comprehension is a straightforward way, but there are alternatives

```
>>> map(list,zip(p))
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

or

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> map(list,izip(p))
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```